# Is there any way for Netsuite to connect to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, netsuite

I want to connect to a SQL Server database from Netsuite and then sync data to Netsuite.

Is there any way I can do it?

Comment: Have you even tried? Have you consulted the "Netsuite" documentation and/or website to see if it can be done - and how?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can do the ODBC connection between NetSuite and your SQL server.You can do it similarly with any other SQL Server. However,Syncing the data back would require a web-service.

A linked server needs to be setup using the MS Management Studio. Below are the steps:
(MSDASQL has to be downloaded and installed piror to following the steps below if not yet preinstalled with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.)

1. Open MS SQL Management Studio and go to Server Objects > Linked Servers > Providers menu tree. Right click the MSDASQL and set these options:

   - Dynamic parameter
   - Nested Queries
   - Allow inprocess
   - Supports 'Like' operator
2. Right click on Linked Servers, select New Linked Server and on the General tab, set the following:

   - Linked Server: NETSUITE
   - Provider: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers
   - Product Name: NetSuite.com
   - Data Source: NetSuite.com //Copy the DSN name from ODBC Data Source
   - Provider String: DSN=NetSuite.com

On the Security tab, select *be made using this security context, and enter Login email and password

3. Try to execute SQL to test the connection

Select * from [Linked Server].[Company Name].Administrator.Accounts

Note:

1. This procedure is also applicable to MS SQL Server 2008.
2. [Company Name] is the one found at Setup > Company > Company Information > Company Name

---

The following table lists tasks for an ODBC driver to connect to Connect Service; however, some of these tasks are optional to complete(refer suite Answer Id: 38942)

| Task | Description |
| --- | --- |
| Set up an environment and verify installation prerequisites. | For both Windows and Linux, see Prerequisites to verify the installation prerequisites. |
| Download and install the driver. | For Windows, see Downloading and Installing the ODBC Driver for Windows.For Linux, see Downloading and Installing the ODBC Driver for Linux. |
| Set up the ODBC connection. | For Windows, see Configuring the ODBC Data Source on Windows.For Linux, see Configuring the ODBC Data Source on Linux. |
| Optionally, upgrade from a previous version. | For both Windows and Linux, see Upgrading an ODBC Driver to upgrade a previous installation. |
| Optionally, enable authentication with server certificates. | For both Windows and Linux, see Authentication Using Server Certificates for ODBC to add increased encryption to secure the data connection. |